# JPA MySQL sort by a list's element attribute(s)

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have two entities in my system

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @ManyToMany()
  private List<Book> books;
}

@Entity
public class Book {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String Volume;
  private String pageNumber;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
  private List<Person> people;

}
```

Essentially a person can appear in multiple books , and books can reference multiple people.

I am using spring data with jpa and exposing a service that returns paged results where I will be able to sort using the sort parameter (such as /service/people?sort=name)

I have a requirement to sort the people in the order they appear in a given book defined by the id of the book.

Is there a way to list all the people in the order they appear in book id 4 for example (sort by the volume and pageNumber in book 4), no matter what the order is in other books? What would the SQL query be? And is it doable with JPA?

It's ok to assumer that All books are associated with all "persons"

Comment: That can be done by using spring data Specifications and Querydsl.

You can create any type of customised query using JPA Criteria API.

Check Spring documentation for more information

Click here for spring data documentation

Comment: What does it mean to "sort by the volume and pageNumber" in a single book?

Comment: @JensSchauder Lets say 3 people P1, P2, and P3 appears in 3 Books B1 , B2 and B3. I want to sort the people in the order the appear in B2 only no matter what the order is in the other books.

Comment: Try `select p from person p join book b where b.id = 4 order by b.volume, b.pageNumber`, I'm too lazy to actually try it right now.